# Extending REST class and override methods on the same path

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, inheritance, jax-rs

I will just provide an example because I find it hard to put the correct question.

I have a REST(Jersey) class with some methods.

```
@Path(value = "{resource}")
public class GenericRestResource{
//some methods
}
```

And I have a class which extends it.

```
public class SomeClass extends GenericRestResource{
//override parent methods
}
```

Is it possible to extend GenericRestResource class like this to override its methods on the same @Path?

Will SomeClass gain the same @Path attribute as his parent class?

Or this is done in another way?

Thank you.

Comment: It is generally not advisable to override concrete code. Either, the method you want to override should be abstract, empty or final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about subresources.  The java ee 7 tutorial has a good section on them. [31.3 Subresources and Runtime Resource Resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-advanced003.htm#GKNAV)